Sourcing a script in different byobu terminals or source once and give that to different byobu terminals
I do have a script that needs to be sourced before other commands work. Sourcing this script takes some time and unfortunately, it is not possible to source this script twice at the same time. Basically, I need different terminals, in which this script is sourced. Currently, I am trying to do this with byobu but I am also open to other possibilities.
One possibility is to source this script and then start byobu with this sourced script. But I do not know, how this can be done. Another possibility I see is to start byobu, source this script in one terminal and source it in the next terminal for example three seconds later. I do not know how to handle that either.
I would prefer the first solution but I am also open to others if that does not work. Thank you very much!
I tried sourcing the script in the file ~/.byobu/prompt but sourcing the file multiple times did not work.
